Blender set driven key like in Maya
Does blender have a direct equivalent to Maya's "Set Driven Key" that allows you to simply pose the bones and set keys in a straightforward, non-scripted manner. I have multiple fingers and I need one master bone influence all fingers (pose fist). Blender current driver workflow is slow and unintuitive, because I need to set the driver, calculate the rotation for finger and do it for all of the other fingers, while in Maya I just set a pose and add a Driven Key for all the fingers.
Maybe there is already an addon that simplifies the process, I don't know about?


Sure. Select all the bones you want to keyframe in Pose mode and hit 'I' You can also turn on Auto keying from the icon at the top of the timeline window.

Adding a key is not equivalent to maya set driven Key
